# Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET Performance Instrumentation "Unable to locate 'vsinstr.exe at ."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to profile an ASP.NET website, but have been stuck with a peculiar error shown in the Performance Output. Whenever I traffic the development site that the profiler started I get a line:

> "Unable to locate 'vsinstr.exe' at ."

Searching for some time and I have been unable to resolve this... any suggestions??

Note, I've literally gone to every google result for "Unable to locate 'vsinstr.exe' at ."; there are only 10 or so.  Also, I tried to use vsperfaspnetcmd to profile the same site that I have setup in IIS and I get:

> C:\Windows\system32>vsperfaspnetcmd /t /s /i http://example.com Microsoft
>   (R) VSPerf ASP.NET Command, Version 11.0.0.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Configuring and attaching to ASP.NET process. Please wait.
>
> Error VSP 7008: ASP.net exception: "The web site could not be
>   configured correctly; ge tting ASP.NET process information failed.
>   Requesting 'http://example.com/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error:
>   The remote server returned an e rror: (403) Forbidden."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows 8 64 Bit VS 2012 Ultimate.

Does the browser window launches after the error ""Unable to locate 'vsinstr.exe' at ." ?

If so, what was the latest change you did ? In our case we were running the app pool ".Net 4.5" later changed that to "Default", though the error was there but the profile continues to run further browser launched with the ASP .Net Web Application and we were able to collect instrumentation.